# Customizing Sharepoint Online Login Branding

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, login, azure-ad, custom-login-page

Our SharePoint online/Office 365 cloud instance has received Microsoft's final push to remove the "old experience" to logging in. Our users can no longer select "keep me signed in" as a result.

We tried adding [company branding](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/customize-branding) to the sign-in page and selecting Yes for the "Show option to remain signed in", but it doesn't seem to work. Here's [the link](https://aad.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/LoginTenantBrandingBlade) for you to try changing it on your own instance. We've waited well past the hour implementation timeline and have tried across multiple browsers after clearing cache, etc etc.

[image]

I'm wondering if this custom company branding was intended for the "old experience" and not the new. Anybody out there had success adding that remain signed in checkbox in the new experience?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Office 365 is replacing the “keep me signed in” checkbox with a prompt that displays after the user successfully signs in. This prompt asks the user if they’d like to remain signed in. If a user responds “Yes” to this prompt, the service gives them a persistent refresh token. This is the same behavior that currently occurs when a user checks the “Keep me signed in” checkbox. For federated tenants, this prompt will show after the user successfully authenticates with the federated identity service.

[image]

Admins can choose to hide this new prompt for users by using the “Show option to remain signed in” setting in [company branding](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/customize-branding).

Refer to: [The new “Keep me signed in” experience for Azure AD is in preview](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2017/09/19/fewer-login-prompts-the-new-keep-me-signed-in-experience-for-azure-ad-is-in-preview/)

Comment: Right, I understand all that. We checked "Yes" for the "Show option to remain signed in" in the settings in company branding. It's been way more than the recommended hour, and it still isn't showing up. What I'm asking is if there is something I am missing that I still need to do or perhaps some other reason why it wouldn't show up.